# Choosing the right Html 5 framework - HTML5 Boilerplate, Skeleton, Twitter Bootstrap and HTML KickStart

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, html5boilerplate, html5-kickstart

I need advice on selecting one of the above frameworks for **HTML5 UI** development (I am quite new to this end of the world). One of the main requirement is to keep the UI development as simple as possible by reusing/modifying the existing UI controls.

We need it to be **lightweight** and stable in the production environment (which speaks with Spring MVC). A quick summary of PRO's and Con's from the experienced hands would be really helpful.

**P.S.** Influenced by few good reviews on **HTML Kickstart**(lightweight nature), I had a quick look  and it seems to be good bet with handful number of UI controls (roots from Font Awesome). I am little apprehensive about its stability / flexibility  in productions environment.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: In case you do chose [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), consider [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/) for even faster development

Comment: I'd say: ALWAYS use boilerplate. SOMEtimes use TBS. Pure is a great new lightweight library.

Answer (score 3):

For the visual, support, quality -> Twitter Bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap and HTML5 Boilerplate are from different goals but complement each other.

For more good and condensed and complete, read this book **[HTML5 Enterprise Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849685681)**, have a lot of things explained, not in detail, but will show some names, and you can chose you want.

Answer (score 2):

These are the most common nowadays:

- http://getbootstrap.com/
- http://foundation.zurb.com/
- http://semantic-ui.com/

Answer (score 2):

About HTML Kickstart i saw it and i think doesn't have an updated view, almost always the frameworks front-end has a structure of 12 columns, so Bootstrap use 12 columns, and has a community very active. About HTML5 Boilerplate is a starting point to build a web page in HTML5 so both have differents targets and both can help each other. So you can use both. Skeleton is another rival of Bootstrap and i think if you need build a website with menu, navbar, lists, tables, slider, forms, etc. Bootstrap has these components, so you would need only copy and paste, while Skeleton is only a basic structure of columns, not more.

So the best is use both, HTML5 Boilerplate with Bootstrap, both can give you a website safe and responsive.